# "No parameterless constructor defined" error when attempting DI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am trying to register a class for dependency inject, however when I tried to inject it through my constructor I get the following error:

> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'MauiClient.MainPage'

I register my service in the main program file as follows:

`MainProgram.cs`:

```
using Accounting.Shared.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MauiClient
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

            builder.Services.AddTransient<ITestService>(s =>
            {
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var token = "";
                return new TestService(httpClient, token);
            });

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

My actual service class - `TestService.cs`:

```
namespace Accounting.Shared.Services;

public interface ITestService
{
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private string _token;

    public TestService(HttpClient httpClient, string token)
    {        
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _token = token;
    }
}
```

And finally in `MainPage.xaml.cs` I attempt the dependency injection:

```
namespace MauiClient;

using Accounting.Shared.Services;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    private ITestService _testService;

    public MainPage(ITestService testService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _testService = testService; 
    }

    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

I cannot see why it's failing to pass it as a parameter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show where `MainPage` is instantiated.

Comment: @ewerspej forgive my ignorance, this is my first maiu project so i'm not sure, this is simply a blank MAUI project.  Where would it normally be instantiated?

Comment: Well, either you're having some code where it says `new MainPage()` somewhere or it's registered either as a Route or it's used in a `<ShellContent>`.

Comment: @ewerspej in AppShell.xaml I have: <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="MainPage" />  However, the answer you posted solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register not only the `ITestService`, but also the `MainPage`, when using it with `<ShellContent>`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITestService>(s =>
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var token = "";
    return new TestService(httpClient, token);
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();

return builder.Build();
```

This is because Shell can only use parameterless constructors on its own.

Comment: This may have been my own doing by accidentally removing that line.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not part of the template as it's only required when using DI.